# How to plot boundary lines for max and min values on each plot in python seaborn?

Tags: python

suppose I am plotting scatter plot in seaborn python

```
    import seaborn as sns
    df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="flipper_length_mm", y="body_mass_g",hue="sex",s=300)
```

What I want is boundary lines of max and min values in each scale.
The question might be hard to understand. If you didn't understand you can tell me

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for vertical and horizontal lines on the x and y axis at the min and max values of your data?

Comment: yes exactly thats what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate your min and max values for each axis. You can use the panda DataFrame methods `.min()` and `.max()` for that respectively.

To add them as lines to your scatterplot you can use the matplotlib.pyplot methods, `.axhline()` and `.axvline()` for your horizontal/y-axis and vertical/x-axis.

For example adding a horizontal min line:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
graph = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="flipper_length_mm", y="body_mass_g",hue="sex",s=300)
graph.axhline(df['body_mass_g'].min())
```

Comment: that i already know but can you share full code

Comment: To add the rest of the lines to your scatterplot, duplicate the last line of code in the example and adjust.